# Selectively applying image style to a class

Tags: media

On a page that displays pictures that have two different classes, how to I apply an image style to one class and not to the other?

Or, how do I apply different image styles to images that have different classes?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image styles and HTML classes on images are completely unrelated, so you would have to do some sort of manual hack to achieve this. A very basic effort might be to use `hook_preprocess_image_style` like so:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_image_style(&$vars) {
  if (array_search('some-class', $vars['attributes']['class']) !== FALSE) {
    $vars['style_name'] = 'some_style';
  }
  elseif ($another_condition) {
    $vars['style_name'] = 'some_other_style';
  }
}
```